# How do you hide the status bar for SpriteKit games?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fullscreen, statusbar, sprite-kit

I'm writing a game for iOS using SpriteKit. I want to game to be full-screen, no status bar, etc. How do I hide the status bar?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

...and just like that... I found it...

in the view controller:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
  return YES;
}
```